# Silverlight SOS 5.1.40620 for WinDbg is missing

Tags: silverlight, windbg, silverlight-5.0, sos

I already downloaded the latest SDK and Runtime. The older runtime 5.1.40416 contains the SOS extension. Where do i get the current one?

Is it possible to convince WinDbg to use the old one as an alternative?

Comment: How did you check that it is not included?

Comment: 2 simple ways 1. The dll is missing 2. The downloaded SDK has Version "5.1.40416" and the current runtime has Version "5.1.40620"

Comment: I even don't have a SOS.dll for 5.1.40416...

Comment: You can't convince WinDbg to use the old one. But you can try to find it online through knowledge base articles: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/05/19/obtaining-mscordacwksdll-for-clr-versions-you-dont-have/ It might also be worth a shot trying to download it from the Microsoft symbol server.